# Find time duration between two consecutive states in pyspark or hive

Tags: sql, hive, pyspark, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which looks like below having columns: 
`ID, STATE and TIMESTAMP`. 
Data frame is sorted as per `ID and TIMESTAMP`.
We need to find out the time gap in between `state S1 to S2`.

**NOTE: For a particular ID, we can have multiple transitions between S1 to S2. And state will always starts with S1 and ends with S2.**

Look at the image attached for more info:

[Input in Blue and expected output in Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGUfP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     select id, 
        unix_timestamp(timestamp) - 
        unix_timestamp(lag(timestamp) over(partition by id order by timestamp)) as time_diff
        from table;
```